# Sonar integration with lizard to track code complexity failing in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, sonarqube, complexity-theory, code-complexity

I am trying to integrate [lizard](https://github.com/terryyin/lizard) to track the code complexity of an android app on sonarqube. The command used to get the complexity report from lizard is:

```
lizard src/main -x"./test/*" -x"./androidTest" --xml >lizard/lizardReport.xml
```

In the `build.gradle` file of the app, the sonarqube properties are configured as follows:

```js
sonarqube { 
  properties { 
    property "sonar.sourceEncoding", "UTF-8" 
    property "sonar.host.url", "https://a.com/“ 
    property "sonar.login", “abc”  property "sonar.password", “abc”  property "sonar.projectKey", "abcd" 
    property "sonar.projectName", "ABCD" 
    property "sonar.projectVersion", android.defaultConfig.versionName  property "sonar.sources", "./src/main" 
    property "sonar.exclusions", "**/*test*/**,build/**,*.iml,**/*generated*" 
    property "sonar.tests", "./src/test/" 
    property "sonar.test.inclusions", "**/*test*/**" 
    property "sonar.import_unknown_files", true  property "sonar.java.lizard.report", "lizard/lizardReport.xml" 
  }
}
```

At the end of this setup, I am running the `gradle sonarqube` command to build the project and run the sonar setup but on viewing the report on the sonarqube dashboard, there is no trend for code complexity.

Is there something I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

```js
sonarqube {
properties {
    property "sonar.sourceEncoding", "UTF-8"
    property "sonar.host.url", "https://a.com/"
    property "sonar.login", "abc"
    property "sonar.password", "abc"
    property "sonar.projectKey", "abcd"
    property "sonar.projectName", "ABCD"
    property "sonar.projectVersion", android.defaultConfig.versionName
    property "sonar.sources", "./src/main"
    property "sonar.exclusions", "**/*test*/**,build/**,*.iml,**/*generated*"
    property "sonar.tests", "./src/test/"
    property "sonar.test.inclusions", "**/*test*/**"
    property "sonar.import_unknown_files", true
    property "sonar.java.lizard.report", "lizard/lizardReport.xml"
}
}
```

Removed the extra quotation mark after the SonarQube host URL  "https://a.com/“ -->  "https://a.com/"

- eplaced the curly quotation marks (“ and ”) around the values of sonar.login and sonar.password with regular double quotation marks (")
- removed the extra space before property "sonar.java.lizard.report", "lizard/lizardReport.xml" for consistency.
- check the corrected properties are correctly placed within the sonarqube block in your build.gradle file.